# How to create a function that looks at individual letters in a string?

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to make a function that will take in DNA strings and then complement them out (i.e. if A, give T and if G, give C [vice versa]).

So far I have this code:

```
def Complement(DNA):
    DNA = input("Enter your DNA string:")
    if DNA == 'A':
        result = 'T'
    elif DNA == 'T':
        result = 'A'
    elif DNA == 'G':
        result = 'C'
    else:
        result = 'G'
    return (result)
```

But, python is picking up the 4 'digit' string as an 'else' and results in G as output. How can I alter this code so that anyone can enter a random letter/size DNA string and the function will complement each letter?
This code works if you have just one letter in the DNA string which isn't really helpful :/

THANKS

Comment: are you looking at the first letter or if DNA variable contains that letter.  Your code will compare the value that is stored in DNA to 'A' or 'T'  etc.. If  DNA is ABC it is not equal 'A' but if DNA is just 'A' then the two strings are equal.  This is the reason if you have any strings that is more then one letter then these strings will be equal to any of the characters and result will be set to G

Comment: The code is working for me, please provide a version of your input. Also, use `raw_input` instead of `input` for security reasons. Finally, either you remove `DNA` from the parameters list, or you remove the `input` statement because you don't need both of them :)

Comment: @Yan I think she(or he) is saying she(or he) wants their solution to work with input longer than 1-character.

Comment: @Ambitions FYI, `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3. (Not sure which language is being used here, of course.)

Comment: python 3^ the raw_input didn't help with the length of string issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the string DNA to compare each of its character. In your case, you are comparing the whole string DNA to individual characters.

```
DNA = input("Enter your DNA string:")
for i in DNA:
    if i == 'A':
        result = 'T'
    elif i == 'T':
        result = 'A'
    elif i == 'G':
        result = 'C'
    else:
        result = 'G'
```

You may want to store the result somewhere so instead of overwriting the value of result, you can append it to result

```
def Complement(DNA):
    result = ""
    for i in DNA:
        if i == 'A':
            result = result + 'T'
        elif i == 'T':
            result =result +  'A'
        elif i == 'G':
            result = result + 'C'
        else:
            result = result + 'G'
    return (result)
```

Comment: Okay, one question, why does the result have to be put there right before the for loop? Can't the result just be: result = 'T' or would that not work? Also, thanks for the loop suggestion, I hadn't even thought of it...

Comment: Because if you put it inside the for loop, it will be reinitialized to empty string ("") after every iteration.

Comment: If you use result = 'T' then after every iteration you will overwrite the value of result with the new value. result = result + 'T' creates a new string which    is a concatenation of result and 'T'. So that your final result is the combined result of each iteration.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help! Your code was the easiest to understand considering my novice level in python. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Python's [string translate method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) was designed for exactly this kind of problem:

```
>>> import string
>>> xlat = string.maketrans('atgcATGC', 'tacgTACG')
>>> 'gattaca'.translate(xlat)
'ctaatgt'
```

The *xlat* variable is a translation table.  The *str.translate()* method takes a string and applies the translation table.

Comment: Python literally has a function for everything. It's really cool.  It's even more amazing that you can even remember that.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
def complement():
    # read the DNA sequence from stdin
    dna = input("Enter your DNA string:")

    # start with an empty result
    result = ""

    # iterate over each character of the sequence, and
    # add the corresponding character to the result
    for character in dna:
        if character == "A":
            result += "T"
        elif character == "T":
            result += "A"
        elif character == "G":
            result += "C"
        elif character == "C":
            result += "G"

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

An **easy method** of doing this would be by using dictionaries.

Also, this is **non case sensitive** as I call the **.upper()** string function before looping.

```
di = {
    "A":"T",
    "T":"A",
    "G":"C",
    "C":"G"
}

def Complement(DNA):
    result = ""
    for char in DNA.upper():
        result += di[char]
    return (result)

print(Complement("ATGC"))
print(Complement(input("Enter your DNA string: ")))
```

Comment: Funny you should mention that. We actual have an "official" term here at SO for that called [FGITW(Fastest Gun In The West)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stack+overflow+fastest+gun+in+the+west&*).

Comment: Yeah, that messes me up when I go super in detail.  This was a more superficial problem, so I really didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you the option of having a string of any length:

```
def Complement():
    print("Enter your DNA string: ")
    DNA = str(input())
    result = ''
    for i in DNA:
        if i == 'A':
            result = result + 'T'
        elif i == 'T':
            result = result + 'A'
        elif i == 'G':
            result = result + 'C'
        else:
            result = result + 'G'
   return result
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful! Especially because the string can be unlimited.